# How to get list item position in list view?

Tags: android, listview

My code populates package names from a `.txt` file into a ListView, and I want to make every list item open itself in Google Play Store when clicked. How do I get the list item (package name)?

```
startActivity(new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                    + "com.utorrent.client")));
```

My list view:

```
    try {
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/vers.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(filePath), "Cp1252"), 100);

        String line;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        br.close();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lines);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use an `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set onItemClickListener on your listview and then from the position of clicked item get that item from your dataList.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                + lines.get(position))));
     }
 });
```

Comment: @joey From your code, lines is an ArrayList where you store your package names. So try to put ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(); as a global variable.

Comment: no there is no need to make this global variable adapter can be used for that purpose

Comment: This answer may open your app link in browser. To open Google Play Store directly use `Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + lines.get(position))` instead whole url.

Comment: How to get the right position even if I scroll the listView?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for you problem. I implemented the same using this code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String recipes = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(Main22Activity.this, recipes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my packagename "));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
try{
    InputStream inputreader = getAssets().open("vers.txt");
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputreader));

    /*  Enter your code here */
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has already an answer but my answer has proper way to get the item of specific position

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object obj = mListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        //Now this object has everything you need to get

    }
});
```